# Minimum sum of distances of G for spanning tree of G

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a undirected simple graph, and $\Omega(G)$ denote the set of spanning trees of G. Does the next funcion
$$l(G) = \min_{T \in \Omega(G)}\quad \sum_{uv \in E} \mbox{dist}_T(u,v)$$
have a specific name? Or has it been studied before?.

The problem is NP-hard, but I'm particularly interested in lower bounds of $l(G)$. Both for general graphs and for specific topologies.

Comment: I think this problem is exactly the same as the one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285998/).